# How to create files from template in rails lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rubygems

I am writing a gem and to use it, some directories, ruby classes and yaml files should be created in rails lib directory. I'd like to have a scaffold method, which creates appropriate files with basic information, that will be modified later. How should I do this?

Should I add something to 'script' directory or to 'script/generate'? Where to store templates? Just for convenience I was using temporary solution: ruby script that creates files and then just puts content as strings line by line, but I don't like it at all and it doesn't seem much a ruby way...

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Rails Guide on Generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

They use the gem Thor under the hood.

Comment: Wow! As I work mostly with rails 2, I check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/ by default and there is nothing about generators, that's why I didn't know about that guide. I even looked into bundler code and found out that it uses thor, but I didn't go any further. Thanks a lot!